# C# Using != operator inside ?:

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, operator-keyword, inequality

I'm trying learn how the inequality operator (!=) works. I can understand the basics of the operator. It returns "true" if the operands are not equal and "false" otherwise.

***But I don't seem to be able to wrap my mind around this particular example we've been given in programming class:***

1. I set the public string for the Unity editor and I don't input any text.
2. The two quote marks ("") mean that text is inputted on the public string.
3. But in this case the condition must be ¿true? because I didn't input any text

Why is the condition returning "false" and the console debugging "Hello Player 1"??? Isn't the condition "true" therefore the conditional operator has to return the *first expression* instead of the *second expression*?

```
public string playerName;

void OnDisable() {
    playerName = (playerName != "") ? playerName : "Player 1";
    Debug.Log("Hello " + playerName);
```

Comment: looks like playerName would be null, not ""

Comment: It's setting `playerName`. If `playerName` is not equal to an empty string, it sets `playerName` to itself (resulting in no change in its value) -- otherwise, it sets it to `"Player 1"`. But as @snow_FFFFFF notes, `playerName` starts out `null`, not an empty string.

Comment: No, false is the _result_ of the evaluation, so playerName is not unequal to "", what means, it equals ""

Comment: Null isn't the same as an empty string. If playerName is null, you get true, which selects playerName

Comment: @Psi since a `string` can be `null` and `null` is != to "", the evaluation would yield `false`.

Comment: My "no" was the reply to the last sentence in the question itself. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: It's very surprising how many people **don't** read the question and come up with unrelevant answers.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey ... and get wildly upvoted for it.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey I guess the reason is: this is such a weird example with so inconvenient logic applied to it... I tried to explain my thought process and doubts as clearly as possible tho...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have that number 2 wrong.
`""` represents an empty string, that is, a string that contains 0 characters.

Since you didn't input any text, `playerName` is equal to `""`, hence `playerName != ""` returns `false`, which is why you see `Hello Payer 1`.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR! I got it now, I though the two quote marks meant that some text was to be inputted on the Unity inspector "text box" for that public string. But instead it means that it is a string containing no characters at all.

Comment: also feel free to read [Ed Plunkett's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42658637/562839) answer. While we get to the same conclusion, his is more through.

Answer (score 11):

If `playerName` is `null`, that is different than being an empty string, `""`

If you want to check for emptyness, i suggest the following:

```
playerName = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(playerName) ? playerName : "Player 1";
```

Comment: 20 seconds late :)

Comment: @TânNguyễn none of this has to do with C# 6, you'll have to clarify

Comment: how can this be upvoted?! If you pay attention to what the OP described, you'll find that `playerName` is not `null`, but an empty string.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey because by making a global variable without assigning to it, `public string playerName;` means it will be `null`

Comment: He even explicitly stated in #1 AND #3 that he never assigned to it.

Comment: @maksymiuk Read the question carefully one more time and the outcome that the OP described and let me know if you still think that `playerName` is `null`.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey of course it is `null`, did you even read/understand my comments?

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey OP explicitly stated himself in #1 and #3 that he never assigned a value to `playerName`, along with the fact that you can see the declaration of `playerName` without a value.

Comment: if it was `null`, how could the OP see `Hello Player 1`?

Comment: because he is assigning to it after the ternary, `playerName = (playerName != "") ? playerName : "Player 1";` <--- this assigns a value to `playerName`

Comment: and since `playerName` is `null`, it does not equal `""`, hence assigning `"Player 1"` value

Comment: it's probably late your way. I suggest that you come back to that question with a clear mind. Trying that ternary in Visual Studio with `playerName` set to `null` might surprise you, too...

Answer (score 1):

Your string might be `null`.

I would use

`playerName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(playerName) ? playerName: "Player 1";`

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down:

This expression checks to see if `playerName` is not equal to an empty string. If it's not an empty string, it returns the value of `playerName`. If it *is* an empty string, it returns `"Player 1"` instead.

```
(playerName != "") ? playerName : "Player 1";
```

So: "If we have a valid player name, use that; otherwise, call him "Player 1".

And we assign the result of that expression back to `playerName`:

```
playerName = (playerName != "") ? playerName : "Player 1";
```

The effect is to use a default `playerName` if we don't have a value.

I don't like the use of a conditional expression for that. It's a weird, unclear idiom in my view. Also, as everybody else notes, your `playerName` defaults to `null`, which *is not equal to the empty string*. Meaning you'll get `null` instead of `"Player 1"` if you didn't get any input.

This is the same logic, more readable, and also checks for `null`:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(playerName)) {
    playerName  = "Player 1";
}
```

It's good to learn the conditional operator, and in a class, you're there to learn. But if you come back to your prof and say "this is the same logic but it's more clear", he'd better not dock you any points.

That said, you'd better know *why* it's the same logic, not just take some random cartoon robot's word for it off the internet.

Comment: So true, yeah we are taking an approach of learning first the basics and the different ways to use logic in code, even if some of those ways are weird and unconvenient. The person imparting the course points that out all the time. But in this particular example he wasn't clear enough with the meaning of the two quote marks ("")

Comment: And also thank you for the in-depth clarification. I had pretty much else clear on my mind, but the ("") was driving me crazy and it started to make the rest of the logic unclear for me. I suspected that was the issue, since I was rechecking the official C# Visual Studio documentation and all the logic checked out except that **inequality operator** and the **two quote marks**